# STP Packet Filtering

Tags: linux, networking, stp, ebtables

I have a KVM host with guests joined to a virtual bridge for networking.

[Netdata](https://github.com/netdata/netdata) on guests of this system drew my attention to packets being dropped at the network interface level (the metric reported as `RX dropped` by `ifconfig`).

I tracked the dropped packets to STP (spanning tree protocol) broadcasts from outside of the host. The virtual bridge on the host has STP off, but these packets from other switches on the network are still forwarded to guests.

```
# tcpdump -i enp2s0 stp -etn
30:23:03:27:7c:27 > 01:80:c2:00:00:00, 802.3, length 38: LLC, dsap STP (0x42) Individual, ssap STP (0x42) Command, ctrl 0x03: STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id fffe.30:23:03:27:7c:27.8001, length 43
# tcpdump -i enp1s0 stp -etn
10:06:45:e6:24:0b > 01:80:c2:00:00:00, 802.3, length 38: LLC, dsap STP (0x42) Individual, ssap STP (0x42) Command, ctrl 0x03: STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 8000.10:06:45:e6:24:0b.8004, length 43
```

**Question**

How can I drop STP packets being forwarded through the virtual bridge?

I tried to filter by the dsap/ssap number, but this didn't work.

```
ebtables -A FORWARD -p LENGTH --802_3-sap 0x42 -j DROP
```

*alternatively, I'd be interested in any reasons why this is not a good idea*.

Comment: I have a very similar problem, but still haven't found a solution. Please, let me know if you find something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the dropped packets mean is that no kernel subsystem has registered STP as a supported protocol; the ethernet driver doesn't know where to send the packet, so drops it and increments the dropped counter. This is itself fine, but Netdata treats the rising counter as a possible issue.

The simplest way to fix this is make the kernel/driver aware of STP:

```
sudo modprobe stp
```

This should result in the STP packets being dropped by STP driver rather than the ethernet driver.

On most Linux distros you can make this permanent by adding `stp` to `/etc/modules`.

Comment: simple solution, thanks.

Comment: If you are configuring the Linux yourself then there is no "CONFIG_STP" option exposed in "make menuconfig" but STP support will be added indirectly by enabling CONFIG_BRIDGE.